# Check if object has a set of properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties, operators

Let's say I have an object named `a`, how could I check that `a` has a specific list of multiple properties in shorthand, I think it can be done using **in** logical operator,

**Something like this:**

```
var a = {prop1:{},prop2:{},prop3:{}};
if ({1:"prop1",2:"prop2",3:"prop3"} in a)
    console.log("a has these properties:'prop1, prop2 and prop3'");
```

**EDIT**

If plain javascript can't help, jQuery will do, but i prefer javascript

**EDIT2**

Portability is the privilege

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The simplest away is to use a conventional `&&`:

```
if ("prop1" in a && "prop2" in a && "prop3" in a) 
    console.log("a has these properties:'prop1, prop2 and prop3'");
```

This isn't a 'shorthand', but it's not that much longer than what you've proposed.

You can also place the property names you want to test in an array and use the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```
var propertiesToTest = ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"];
if (propertiesToTest.every(function(x) { return x in a; })) 
    console.log("a has these properties:'prop1, prop2 and prop3'");
```

Note however, that this was introduced in ECMAScript 5, so it is not available on some older browsers. If this is a concern, you can provide your own version of it. Here's the implementation from MDN:

```
if (!Array.prototype.every) {
  Array.prototype.every = function(fun /*, thisp */) {
    'use strict';
    var t, len, i, thisp;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    t = Object(this);
    len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    thisp = arguments[1];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t && !fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t)) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  };
}
```

Comment: I believe it works, now, is there a more elegant solution? :) Conventional way will be much too long if our list of properties is long, the second solution looks like a good shot, lets see

Comment: Ow, and does every require jQuery?

Comment: @Benedictus No, this is vanilla JS.

Comment: Sorry, it's no good if it doesn't work on older browsers :) I guess ill just have to stick to for(a in b) if nothing smoother comes out

Comment: Why not just polyfill every if its useful for you? It's a simple method see his linked mdn documentation

Comment: @megawac , could you post a snippet?

Comment: @megawac It's in the linked MDN documentation, but I've reproduced it here for posterity. See my updated answer.

Comment: Using && does not scale; what if more and more properties need to get tested

Comment: @GeorgeJempty That's precisely why I offered the alternative.

Comment: `Array.prototype.some` could also be used `!['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'].some(prop => !(prop in a));` This has the advantage of possibly returning early.  It is especially good for checking missing where the outer level negation is not required.

Comment: @Paul note that `every` also exits early if any element returns `false`, so it's functionally identical to `some`, just with the Boolean values inverted.

Answer (score 7):

This is where [the underscore.js library](http://underscorejs.org/) really shines.  For instance it provides an already poly-filled `every()` method as suggested in a comment to p.s.w.g.'s answer: http://underscorejs.org/#every

But there's more than one way to do it; the following, while more verbose, may also suit your needs, and exposes you to more of what underscore can do (e.g. _.keys and _.intersection)

```
var a = {prop1:{},prop2:{},prop3:{}};
var requiredProps = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'];
var inBoth = _.intersection(_.keys(a), requiredProps);
if (inBoth.length === requiredProps.length) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: underscore.js does the poly-filling for you (in order to work with older browsers) and is a library that could make you a better code by using it; for instance consider the book "Functional Javascript" (and the free/sampler PDF): http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028857.do

Answer (score 6):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```
var testProps = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'];
var a = {prop1:{},prop2:{},prop3:{}};

var result = testProps.reduce(function(i,j) { return i && j in a }, true);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you polyfill it - its the same as the other answer

Comment: Than the other one is far more informative, sory to remove the answer mark :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var testProps = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4'];
var num = -1, outA;
for(var i in a){
  if(i === testProps[++num])outA[num] = i;
}
console.log('properties in a: '+outA.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more elegant use of the `Object.every()` prototype function to include `try-catch`:

```
try {
  const required = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']
  const data = {prop1: 'hello', prop2: 'world', prop3: 'bad'}
  if (!required.every( x => x in data )) throw new Error('missing property')
  console.log('all properties found')
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message)
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to try it:

```
/* Create an object class */
var obj = function(){ this.attributes = new Array(); }
obj.prototype.addProp = function(value){ this.attributes.push(new attribute(value)); }
obj.prototype.hasProp = function(value){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++){ 
      if(value == this.attributes[i].value) return true; } return false; }
function attribute(value){
    this.value = value;
}
/* Testing object has some value*/
var ob = new obj();
ob.addProp('1');
ob.addProp('2');
ob.addProp('3');
 //* check value index
//alert(ob.attributes[0].value);
 //* check if ob has prop
alert(ob.hasProp('1'));
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/Y3MsV/)