# How to check which combination of variables is defined and proceed accordingly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a use case where a user can pass certain number of variables based on which a specific logic will be performed.

As the combination of variables my differ I trying to think about an elegant way to code this process.

For example user can pass either `name & type` or `email && schoolId && type` other combinations are not supported.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
      const filterByX = (name && type);
      const filterByY = (email && schoolId && type);

      const decision = (filterByX ? 'filterX' : (filterByY ? 'filterY' : null ));

      switch(decision) {
        case 'filterX':
            ... 
            break;
        case 'filterY':
            ... 
            break;
        default:
            console.log('not supported')
      }
```

But I trust that there's a more elegant way to implement such logic.
Would appreciate a suggestion.

Comment: just make it a single `if...else if` it reduces abstraction and duplication (and avoids a nested ternary) and is also a direct conditional encoding of *'user can pass either `name && type` or `email && schoolId && type` other combinations are not supported.'*

Comment: Though if they pass all four you'll need to decide which combination to prioritize

Comment: Related: [Jquery: Check if object has a set of properties in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578705/2791540)

Answer (score 0):

One idea is an object keyed with the bitwise combination of variables.  For instance, if `a`, `b`, `c` are the input bools, each combo you care about can be encoded as an int 0-7.

```js
const boolsToBits = (a,b,c) => {
  return a << 2 | b << 1 | c ;
}
console.log(boolsToBits(true, true, false)) // == 6
```

With that, you can either `switch` on the resulting int, or (better, imo) describe functions corresponding to conditions using data - using an object keyed by the resulting ints.

```js
const actions = {
  7: () => console.log('a, b and c are true'),
  6: () => console.log('a, b are true'),
  2: () => console.log('only b is true'),
}
const defaultAction = () => console.log('a combo not coded for explicitly')

const boolsToBits = (a, b, c) => {
  return a << 2 | b << 1 | c;
}

const handleThreeBools = (a, b, c) => {
  const action = actions[boolsToBits(a, b, c)] || defaultAction;
  action();
}

handleThreeBools(true, true, true);
handleThreeBools(true, true, false);
handleThreeBools(false, true, false);
handleThreeBools(false, true, true);
```

The idea can be generalized for an arbitrary number of bools like this...

```js
const actions = {
  7:  () => console.log('a, b and c are true'),
  6:  () => console.log('a, b are true'),
  2:  () => console.log('only b is true'),
  33: () => console.log('thats a lot of bits!')
}
const defaultAction = () => console.log('a combo not coded for explicitly')

const boolsToBitsN = (...args) => {
  const length = args.length;
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) result |= args[i] << (length - 1 - i);
  return result
}

const handleNBools = (...args) => {
  const action = actions[boolsToBitsN(...args)] || defaultAction;
  action();
}

handleNBools(true, false, false, false, false, true);
```

And of course, the object containing functions keyed by ints can expand accordingly.